# How do I make a wildcard package search using apt-get?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

With yum it was simple: `yum list *xxx*` but this does not work with `apt-get`.

How can I do a search like this?

Also, how do I see what package provides a specific command?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you wish to search a specific string **only in package names**, you can do:

```
apt-cache search --names-only 'xxx'
```

This will return anything that contains '**xxx**' in their package name.

You can also use [**regular expressions**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/):

```
apt-cache search --names-only 'php5$'
```

This will return any package with their name ending in **php5**.

Regular expressions can also be used without the **--names-only**. See **apt-cache(8)** man page.

Comment: aptitude search operates in the same way and you should really be using aptitude rather than apt-get these days.

Comment: kaerast, you enlightened me! aptitude is the way. Thank. You should put this as an answer instead of a comment. "aptitude search"

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is "apt-cache search"

Answer (score 1):

First Question: use dselect or aptitude to see/search all available packagesm, their both curses frontends to apt-get and/or dpkg

Second Question: `dpkg -S <COMMAND>`

It would be wise to include the whole path in your dpkg search (e.g. /bin/ls, not just ls).

Answer (score 0):

Yet another alternative is axi-cache (in the apt-xapian-index package). It uses the xapian search engine to search through the apt archives.

Answer (score 0):

Put the search query in a quotes and then use regex. For install to search whatever version of php-curl, I use;

```
sudo apt-cache search "php.*curl"
```

which returns;

```
php5-curl - CURL module for php5
php-http-request2 - Provides an easy way to perform HTTP requests
```